# Firefox - footer with absolute position not working (no tables)

Tags: html, css, firefox

I came across a minor glitch on firefox. I am trying to position my footer on the bottom of the page. I have found a sticky footer example here: http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

I have adapted the solution there to fit my application.

Here is the code:

**CSS**

```
.footer {
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.content-custom {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div>Header</div>
    <div class="content-custom">Content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

I am including some pages in each section. The trouble I encounter is with the footer. It is working fine in IE and Chrome, but in firefox, the position:absolute is of no use (the footer doesn't stick to the bottom of the page).

I have tried various solutions such as adding the following CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative
}
```

or using

```
.footer {
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 80px; /* adding this as a property */
}
```

but with no success.

Most of the answers I've found provided solutions for users who encountered this problem while using tables, but this is not my case.

Does anyone have an idea of a possible solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: I opened the link you mentioned in different browsers including Firefox and it's working fine everywhere. Maybe you have conflicting styles somewhere, or missed something?

Comment: The link I provided is with the example of the sticky footer that I have adapted. It is not my site. I will double check though, to see if I have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after adapting the solution provided by Muthukumar, this is the final code that got it working for me:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div>Header</div>
    <div class="content-custom">Content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}

.content-custom {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the body and html tags height is 100%, I am also strucked  this problem and i found the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Dont forget to add this -->
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div>Header</div>
    <div class="content-custom">Content</div>
</div>
   <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>




   *{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px; 
    }
    html {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    body{
        height:100%;
        padding-bottom:80px;
    }
    .footer {
        height: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 0;
        width:100%
    }
    .container{
        display:block;  
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this did it. I had to adapt it a little bit to fit my application. I'll be posting it shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:80px;
}
```

Comment: close, but it overlaps with the content div

Comment: Ok use this 
          html, body {
             position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
          }
    .footer {
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q31rfy1y/)

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:80px;   
}
```